# Live Connect automatic signin without browser windows

Tags: rest, authentication, outlook.com, microsoft-account

I'm creating an desktop application that shall manage my outlook.com account in the background, without me having to type in username and password every time I switch on the PC.

I've been going through all the signin variants for the Microsoft account, but not one document mentions how to pass the username and password in form of a REST call or similar, and how the access token can be used thereafter.

I don't want any user interaction, I shall be a pure background process.

How can this be realized?

Comment: Have you found a solution to that problem?

Comment: No, I gave up on this issue and moved over to google's services :-(